# I made a sticky position but it's not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my code.
I'm using bootstrap.
i don't know why but it's not working.
I just set top position to 0 but still not working.
any idea?
Header:

```
<style>
    .background-nav {
        background: #58585858;
        backdrop-filter: blur(45px);
        border: 3px solid #808080;
    }
    .t-0 {
        top: 0;
    }
</style>
<div class="w-100">
    <div class="row justify-content-around position-sticky t-0 p-0 m-0">
        <div class="col-2 text-center p-2 rounded-2 position-sticky t-0 mt-3 background-nav">Home</div>
        <div class="col-7 text-center p-2 rounded-2 position-sticky t-0 mt-3 background-nav">Search</div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center p-2 rounded-2 position-sticky t-0 mt-3 background-nav">Music</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main Code:

```
<div id="navbar"></div>
<section>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/login">login</a>
</section>
<button style="background: red; color: white" id="Shutdown">SHUTDOWN</button>
<div class="meow">.</div>
<div class="meow">....</div>
<div class="meow">....</div>
<div class="meow">....</div>
<div class="meow">....</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

top code will be replaced with #navbar
and this is css for main code

```
.meow {
            height: 5000px;
            width: 200px;
            display: block;
            background: red;
        }
```

I tried setting `top` to 0 or set position to sticky from the element with !important tag

Comment: I don't see any `position: sticky;` in your code.

Comment: @PeterKolosov It's the `position-sticky` in class from bootstrap 4 I think

Comment: You need position sticky AND a top/left/right/bottom-value for it to work (but i think the bs class already adds that). Try applying sticky just to the `div.w-100` and not all child elements

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a working [repro] for debugging details! `It is not working` is not a helpful explanation nor a question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your elements in a container first becuase boostrap adds additional css properties. so do this...

```
<style>
    #container{
      position: sticky; top: 0;
    }
    .background-nav {
        background: #58585858;
        backdrop-filter: blur(45px);
        border: 3px solid #808080;
    }
    .t-0 {
        top: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
<div class="w-100">
    <div class="row justify-content-around position-sticky t-0 p-0 m-0">
        <div class="col-2 text-center p-2 rounded-2 position-sticky t-0 mt-3 background-nav">Home</div>
        <div class="col-7 text-center p-2 rounded-2 position-sticky t-0 mt-3 background-nav">Search</div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center p-2 rounded-2 position-sticky t-0 mt-3 background-nav">Music</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but not working

Answer (score -1):

To be sticky the element has to be in a scroll container.
So try to wrap your nav and the context inside a div and say `overflow: auto`
then `position: sticky` and `top: 0` on the nav should do the trick.
and probably `z-index: 2` and 'background: white` so the nav will be in front and don't look through,

More to read on [mdn position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?retiredLocale=de)

Comment: It is a `Bootstrap-4` question and as such it should be answered based on the framework not regular CSS! With your answer, you miss the actual question because you ignore the fact that BS-classes add just that.